# Google Drive MimeType with charset=utf-16le

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a file with 
`content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-16LE` that I'm uploading to Google Drive via the REST API.

When I preview the file in Drive, it shows me the raw HTML output.

However, when I download and open the file (in Chrome), the output is garbled HTML rather than the actual browser view of the file.

In debugging the file in Drive, it's only setting the content-type to "text/html", and it's not inheriting the "charset=UTF-16LE" that I specify on upload.

Is there another way to specify charset for the file I'm uploading to Drive?

Comment: You may want to check this [site](https://help.surveygizmo.com/help/encode-an-excel-file-to-utf-8-or-utf-16) wherein there are given step by step instructions on how to go about encoding your Excel files to UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the solution but I think could help you.

If it doesn't induce data corruption of your file, you can make your text/html file as a string, with :

```
var myVarString = myVar.toString();
```

and then use this code to set yourself the charset :

```
Utilities.newBlob("").setDataFromString(myVarString, "UTF-8").getDataAsString("UTF-16");
```